# What was the source for Adam's children in the endnotes to Josephus' "The Antiquities of the Jews"?

Tags: historiography, historical-techniques, origins

I was reading Josephus' account of Adam's children in "The Antiquities of the Jews" (located in Book 1, Chapter 2) and noticed that the total number of children that Adam had was not in the text itself, but in the endnotes of the text. Where do these endnotes find their origins?

I specifically am interesting in the origins of [this](http://sacred-texts.com/jud/josephus/ant-1.htm#EndNote%20ANT%201.8b) endnote:

> "The number of Adam's children, as says the old tradition was thirty-three sons, and twenty-three daughters."

Comment: Whoever wrote that entry on sacred-texts.com wrote those footnotes then. You'd have to go ask them what their sources are. It does mention some "old tradition" though, so it would be a good question what that is and what its logic was. Well, I'm curious at least.

Comment: @T.E.D. Seems they're from an earlier translation by William Whiston. He refers to another of his translations of biblical sources (see my answer below).

Comment: Is this really a question about history?

Comment: @Alex it is a question about a historical document. Do you know of a better site this should be on? One could say that this document is part of history.

Comment: A [related](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/21622) question.

Comment: See [Life of Adam and Eve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_of_Adam_and_Eve).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The footnotes on this (and other editions of Josephus) seem to be referring to pages in [A Collection of Authentick Records Belonging to the Old and New Testament](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=aupgAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) by William Whiston.

In this case, [another online version](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/josephus/ant-1.html#EndNote_Ant_1.11b) offers this particular footnote with the reference thus:

> (11) The number of Adam’s children, as says the old tradition, was thirty three sons, and twenty three daughters, in Authent. Rec. Part I. pag. 454, 457, 469.

---

On page 454 of *Authentick Sources*, we read that:

[image: page 454]

and on page 457 we see:

[image: page 457]

---

[William Whiston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Whiston), M.A. produced one of the earliest (possibly the earliest) translations of Josephus into English. The references in the footnotes thus link into another of his translations of "biblical" records.

Copies of the works by the Byzantine scholars [Syncellus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Syncellus) and [Cedrenus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Kedrenos) mentioned by Whiston are available on [archive.org](https://archive.org/index.php) (although the only copies that I found are in Greek), if you are interested in taking your research further.